# Apply constraint (type/interface) for types

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I am constructing a type that consists of unions of other types:

```js
type A = B | C | D // ...
```

I want to want to be sure at compile time that B, C, D, etc. have the shape of a generic template so that the composite is correct. So I need kind of a interface for types or a type for a type.

For example should B "implement" Template:

```js
type Template = { x: string; y: { [key: string]: any } };
type B = {x: "test", y: {test2: number}}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

As @jcalz suggested you can pass a union to a generic type to check if it fits your constraint. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhC2YA2BDY0C8UDeUAeAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3FCEbgNoDWETJ51NAukRRUQUAL5i6AKFCQoAIShZchKACI5qgDSNmUdKQBMRKgFd4AIwhkxY6eGgBhRTnxFVDrTpf7gRqKYsrG1E7WQARZ2U3D20uXB8-AMtrcRCZaABRSNcoAFZbUMcACwgAYzYAHgBVbRgoCDx0KgATYigqgD5nGElJAHo+qAABYGIAWgbIUuAJsjIAezJCqABBDLnFgEZnBxLyirhEVHRtBQAfKCcLjI7egeHRibwpmasFpfTV9feDHb3Kw7INAQU5QC5XKARa63ZYrP5lAEIIEneRgy5osIdIA).

```
type Template = { x: string; y: { [key: string]: any } };
type B = { x: "B", y: { test2: number } }
type C = { x: "C", y: { test2: number } }
type D = { x: "C", y: { test2: number } }
type E = { x: 5 }

type Check<U, T extends U> = T

// @ts-expect-error
type AError1 = Check<Template, B | C | E>

// @ts-expect-error
type AError2 = Check<Template, B | C | D | E>

type A = Check<Template, B | C | D>
```

You can use generics for this, but it gets verbose if you want to have say more then 10 possible types in a union. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhC2YA2BDY0C8UDeUAeAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3FCEbgNoDWETJ51NAukRRUQUAL5i6AKFCQoAIShZshKACI5qgDSNm6UgCYiVAK7wARhDKjR08NADCinCtX2tOnHuCGoJ85etbWQARJ2UiV3cubC8fPwsrGxloKABRMJUAVhsg6ABZFA4AVSoKAHsqAB4YORRiCG0YAEYoCDx0KgATYlha%20sb9VvaILp6auobYAGYhju7eiacqCAA3S0aAFlmR%20fH6pdX12Ezt0YX9rGW1sgA%20J2aoAB9YQeeYGbett8zJSQB6P5QAACwGIAFo2pAAMbACFkMhlMi5KAAQVS8MRLSwBWKpQq1QQyDQkzk2ns2lSN1%20AOBoIheGhsMsCKRyVR6JZg2xhQgJXKVTgiFQ6G0pKg5KgwQpVORKKcON5eIFhOFJLJ2mCNyAA).

```
type Template = { x: string; y: { [key: string]: any } };
type B = {x: "B", y: {test2: number}}
type C = {x: "C", y: {test2: number}}
type D = {x: "C", y: {test2: number}}
type  E = {x: 5}

type MakeUnion<TBase, T1 extends TBase, T2 extends TBase, T3 extends TBase = never, T4 extends TBase = never, T5 extends TBase = never> = T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | T5

// @ts-expect-error
type AError1 = MakeUnion<Template, B, C, E>

// @ts-expect-error
type AError2 = MakeUnion<Template, B, C, D, E>

type A = MakeUnion<Template, B, C, D>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just pass in the union in the first place, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8BrPm). Is there a benefit to breaking it into separate type arguments?

Comment: @jcalz Right, this might be a better option. I was too focused on "making a union", not on just "checking" the constraint. :)

Comment: Thanks, that is already a good answer. For me it would be even better, if I would get the errors at the individual definitions of B,C,D... Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @dude. The error message contains this information `Errors in code
Type 'B | C | E' does not satisfy the constraint 'Template'.
  Property 'y' is missing in type 'E' but required in type 'Template'.`